# Jmeter plugins not installing for Jmeter 3.0

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I was having issue with some missing class error and decided to uninstall and install new version of Jmeter.

I installed the Jmeter plugin manager and selected a plugin from available plugins to install and click on Apply Changes and Restart Jmeter. However I have tried this many times but the selected jmeter plugin does not get installed.

I even looked up on lib/ext folder to make sure the plugins have been installed. Not sure what the problem is here. My java version is 1.8.0_131. I have tried installing on both Jmeter 3.0 and Jmeter 3.3 but kept running into the same issue.

This is the Jmeter log file, if that is of any help -

```
2017/12/18 14:52:41 INFO  - org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManager: Restarting JMeter...2017/12/18 14:52:41 INFO  - org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManager: Starting JMeter Plugins modifications 2017/12/18 14:52:41 WARN  - org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManager: Failed to run plugin cleaner job java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\Documents\Jmeter\apache-jmeter-3.0\lib\ext\jmeter-plugins-manager-0.18.jar
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.copy(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.copy(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Unknown Source)
at org.jmeterplugins.repository.ChangesMaker.getTempPmgrJAR(ChangesMaker.java:63)
at org.jmeterplugins.repository.ChangesMaker.getProcessBuilder(ChangesMaker.java:34)
at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManager.startModifications(PluginManager.java:145)
at org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManager$1.run(PluginManager.java:202)
```

Comment: You are missing plugin manager jar in lib\ext folder

Answer (score 1):

I hope you followed these steps...

1. Download JMeter plugin manager from https://jmeter-plugins.org/install/Install/ and put it in your JMeter's "lib/ext" folder.
2. Now start your JMeter in UI mode.
3. Click Options - you should find "Plugins Manager" option (if not something wrong - download fresh copy of latest JMeter 4.0).
4. Click "Plugins Manager" option.
5. Go to "Available Plugins" tab.
6. Install one at a time (which ever is required) - Installing multiple at a time might cause some problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to remove the existing Jmeter plugin manager and reinstall it in the correct way as follows.
Download and configure the Jmeter plugin manager:

- Browse the following link and download the "Jmeter plugin
  manager" Jar file.
  [Jmeter plugin manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)
- Add copy and paste the downloaded JAR file into "ext" folder to the
  "C:\your location\apache-jmeter-5.3\lib\ext."
  (In my case - C:\Users\My Account\Downloads\apache-jmeter-5.3\lib\ext)
- Restart the Jmeter. (You will see a new icon at the top right corner of your JMeter application if the installation process is completed.)

Note: always use the latest version of JMeter. You can download that from here.
[Jmeter download link -](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi)

### Or.

You can install the plugins directly to the Jmeter as follows.

- Search and download the particular plugin that you want to install. [You can download them using this link](https://jmeter-plugins.org/)
- Go to the "lib" folder which resides within the downloaded plugin folder.
- You can see "jar file/s" and "ext" folder.
- Copy that jar file into the "lib" folder which is located within your JMeter folder.
  (In my case - C:\Users\My Account\Downloads\apache-jmeter-5.3\lib)
- Go to the "ext" folder of your downloaded folder. (You can see another JAR files within that)
- Copy those files to the "ext" folder which is located within your JMeter folder.
  (In my case - C:\Users\My Account\Downloads\apache-jmeter-5.3\lib\ext)
- Restart the Jmeter application.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to download the older version of the plugin as it may have been modified to use the latest version of JMeter. https://jmeter-plugins.org/ provides the plugins. On this site, you can look up for the plugin you need and download the required version as seen in the below image. Extract the zip file and copy the jar in [JMeter Root Directory]/lib/ext directory.
[image: Image for reference.]